# retrieving substring of `\DTLfetch`

Tags: datatool, xstring

I've been trying to get to the substring of a value retrieved by `datatool`'s, macro `\DTLfetch`, but I am unable to control the expansion here. I've tried some `\expandarg` `\fullexpandarg` as well as some `\edef`.

I don't necessarily need to use `datatool` to retrieve the contents or `xstring` to perform the substring-command,, but I am required to not alter the datafile. Otherwise, I would just have `regex`-ed it.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x,y
duck,quack
donkey,hee-haw
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}



\begin{document}

original value:
        \DTLfetch{data}{x}{donkey}{y}%

substring(failing):
% \fullexpandarg%
\expandarg%
\StrRight{%
        \DTLfetch{data}{x}{donkey}{y}%
        }{3}

Expecting output:
\StrRight{%
        hee-haw%
        }{3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg Is there a different package, or some kind of macro that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `\DTLfetch` is not expandable, but there's a way out: `\DTLfetch` saves the returned value in `\dtlcurrentvalue`, so it's just a matter of making *this* available for processing in `\StrRight` and print nothing.

I just copied the definition of `\DTLfetch`, shifting the parameters by one and inserted `\let#1` before `\dtlcurrentvalue` (that is causing the printing). Do `\DTLfetchsave{\temp}{<1>}{<2>}{<3>}{<4>}`, where the last four arguments mean the same as the arguments to `\DTLfetch` and `\temp` is any (unused) control sequence. You can reuse `\temp` or whatever name you chose; be careful to use a “strange name”.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
x,y
duck,quack
donkey,hee-haw
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\DTLfetchsave}[5]{%
  \edtlgetrowforvalue{#2}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#3}}{#4}%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#5}}%
  \let#1\dtlcurrentvalue
}

\DTLloaddb{data}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}

original value:
\DTLfetch{data}{x}{donkey}{y}%

substring:
\DTLfetchsave{\temp}{data}{x}{donkey}{y}%
\StrRight{\temp}{3}

Expecting output:
\StrRight{hee-haw}{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]