# How can I use DTL data to configure a pgfplots axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, datatool

I am importing key-value pairs from a dat file using the package `datatool` like this:

```
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={k,v}]{data}{data/data.dat}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{data}{k}{#1}{v}}
```

After that, the data becomes available using the `\var{key}` command. This works everywhere in the document with all of the key/value pairs from the file. Now I want to use some of this data to configure a `pgfplots` axis. This is my attempt:

```
\begin{axis}[
    % a lot of other settings...
    xmax=\var{xmax}
]
    % ...
\end{axis}
```

But this fails, giving me this error message: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@bgroup@strip@last.` and a bunch of `Undefined control sequence`s

How can I use the imported data to configure pgfplots?

Thank you so much for your help!

## Minimal compatible document

main.tex

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\DTLsetseparator{=}% Set the separator between the columns.
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={k,v}]{data}{data.dat} 
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{data}{k}{#1}{v}}

\begin{document}
\var{xmax} % this works
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmax=\var{xmax} % this doesnt
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

data.dat

```
k=v
xmax=350
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead show a minimal compilable document (even with error) that people can play with.

Comment: @AlanMunn thank you for the hint! i added a minimal compatible document to my question :)

Comment: The problem here is that `\DTLfetch` isn't expandable. A solution would be get the data outside of the plot using the technique [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335483/) rather than trying to do everything inside the plot itself.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved the issue!

Comment: It would be helpful to others to add an answer showing what you did. I didn't write one because I wasn't sure if it would meet your needs.