# How to turn string read from (CSV) file into counter

Tags: counters, input, datatool

I have a csv file with tags and (page) nrs, as follows:

```
tag,nr
t1,1
t2,5
t3,9
```

The nr-column refers to page numbers in a pdf file. Each page has a corresponding tag. Given a tag, I want to show the corresponding page in a figure in my latex document.

With datatools I can load the csv file, and fetch the page nr of a given tag. For example, for tag `t2` I get page nr `5`.

But now when I feed that page nr as the `page=...` argument to includegraphics, I get the error message

> "! Missing number, treated as zero."`

What extra step should I take to convert the latex `5` string into a page nr that includegraphics can handle?

Here's a simplified version (using counters instead of includegraphics) that triggers the problem:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{tags}{prestags.csv}
\newcommand{\pagenr}{\DTLfetch{tags}{tag}{t2}{nr}}

\newcounter{snr}
\addtocounter{snr}{\pagenr}

\end{document}

% Output:

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.10 \addtocounter{snr}{\pagenr}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: AFAIK you need to use `\DTLgetvalue` to define `\pagenr`. (Sorry, cannot test currently).

Comment: The problem is that `\DTLfetch` is not expandable. You can use the technique here: [retrieving substring of \`\DTLfetch\`](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/335483) to overcome this.

Comment: Thanks!! I now got it to work with `DTLgetvalue` in combination with `DTLgetlocation`.  The `dtlcurrentvalue` trick to handle non-expandable results seems nice too. Please feel free to turn your suggestions into answers that I can upvote / accept (I can also do this if that's what you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `\DTLfetch` macro isn't expandable. You can use the technique described here:

- [retrieving substring of `\DTLfetch`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335483)

to overcome this. Here's a worked out example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
tag,nr
t1,1
t2,5
t3,9
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\newcommand{\getvar}[1]{\DTLfetchsave{\myvar}{tags}{tag}{#1}{nr}}
\newcommand{\DTLfetchsave}[5]{%
  \edtlgetrowforvalue{#2}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#3}}{#4}%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#5}}%
  \let#1\dtlcurrentvalue
}
\newcounter{snr}
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{tags}{prestags.csv}

\setcounter{snr}{3}
The counter value is \thesnr

\getvar{t2}
\addtocounter{snr}{\myvar}
The counter value is: \thesnr

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use the `readarray` package to digest the csv file and a `listofitems` read to place the data into an list.  The macro `\getvar` is expandable.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{prestags.csv}
tag,nr
t1,1
t2,5
t3,9
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{prestags.csv}\mycsvdata
\setsepchar{\\/,}
\readlist*{\mycsvlist}{\mycsvdata}
\foreachitem\z\in\mycsvlist[]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname mytag\mycsvlist[\zcnt,1]\expandafter
    \endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter
    \mycsvlist\expandafter[\zcnt,2]}%
}
\newcommand\getvar[1]{\csname mytag#1\endcsname}

The t2 tag corresonds with page \getvar{t2}

\includegraphics[page=\getvar{t3},scale=.6]{readarray.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind defining a scratch-macro globally, you can probably use `\DTLassignfirstmatch`:

When compiling the following example, you get two error messages.

This is on purpose so you can see what happens in case of attempting to retrieve non-existing values.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{prestags.csv}
tag,nr
t1,1
t2,5
t3,9
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyStuffDTLfetchsavePackageError[7]{%
  \PackageError{#1}{#7}{%
    In order to retrieve from database `#2`\MessageBreak
    the value of the key `#5` in the first row\MessageBreak
    where the key `#3` has value `#4`,\MessageBreak
    database `#2` must exist and have keys\MessageBreak
    `#3` and `#5` and a row where the key `#3`\MessageBreak
    has the value `#4`.%
  }%
  \global\let#6=\dtlnovalue
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MyStuffDTLfetchsave}[5]{%
  %#1 = macro to store as result
  %#2 = data base name
  %#3 = key 1
  %#4 = value of key 1
  %#5 = key 2
  \@bsphack
  \DTLifdbexists{#2}{%
    \DTLifhaskey{#2}{#3}{%
      \DTLifhaskey{#2}{#5}{%
        \global\let#1=\dtlnovalue
        \DTLassignfirstmatch{#2}{#3}{#4}{#1=#5}%
        \ifx#1\dtlnovalue\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
        {%
          \MyStuffDTLfetchsavePackageError{My Stuff}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}%
             {In data base `#2' no row's key `#3' holds the value `#4'}%
        }%
      }{%
        \MyStuffDTLfetchsavePackageError{My Stuff}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}%
          {There is no key `#5' in data base `#2'}%
      }%
    }{%
      \MyStuffDTLfetchsavePackageError{My Stuff}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}%
        {There is no key `#3' in data base `#2'}%
    }%
  }{%
    \MyStuffDTLfetchsavePackageError{My Stuff}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}%
      {Data base `#2' doesn't exist}%
  }%
  \@esphack
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcounter{snr}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{tags}{prestags.csv}

\setcounter{snr}{3}%
\noindent The counter value is: \thesnr

\MyStuffDTLfetchsave{\scratchy}{tags}{tag}{t1}{nr}%
\ifx\scratchy\dtlnovalue
  \noindent The value of the key `nr` in the row where the key `tag` has the value `t1` could not be retrieved.

  \noindent Calculations where this value would have been used were not performed.
\else
  \noindent The value of the key `nr` in the row where the key `tag` has the value `t1` is: \scratchy

  \addtocounter{snr}{\scratchy}%
  \noindent After adding that value to the counter, the counter value is: \thesnr
\fi

\MyStuffDTLfetchsave{\scratchy}{tags}{tag}{t2}{nr}%
\ifx\scratchy\dtlnovalue
  \noindent The value of the key `nr` in the row where the key `tag` has the value `t2` could not be retrieved.

  \noindent Calculations where this value would have been used were not performed.
\else
  \noindent The value of the key `nr` in the row where the key `tag` has the value `t2` is: \scratchy

  \addtocounter{snr}{\scratchy}%
  \noindent After adding that value to the counter, the counter value is: \thesnr
\fi

\MyStuffDTLfetchsave{\scratchy}{tags}{tag}{t3}{nr}%
\ifx\scratchy\dtlnovalue
  \noindent The value of the key `nr` in the row where the key `tag` has the value `t3` could not be retrieved.

  \noindent Calculations where this value would have been used were not performed.
\else
  \noindent The value of the key `nr` in the row where the key `tag` has the value `t3` is: \scratchy

  \addtocounter{snr}{\scratchy}%
  \noindent After adding that value to the counter, the counter value is: \thesnr
\fi

\MyStuffDTLfetchsave{\scratchy}{tags}{tag}{t4}{nr}%
\ifx\scratchy\dtlnovalue
  \noindent The value of the key `nr` in the row where the key `tag` has the value `t4` could not be retrieved.

  \noindent Calculations where this value would have been used were not performed.
\else
  \noindent The value of the key `nr` in the row where the key `tag` has the value `t4` is: \scratchy

  \addtocounter{snr}{\scratchy}%
  \noindent After adding that value to the counter, the counter value is: \thesnr
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/277964/cabohah),
the `DTLfetch` line in the question can be replaced by the following two lines:

```
\DTLgetlocation{\rownr}{\colnr}{tags}{t2}
\DTLgetvalue{\pagenr}{tags}{\rownr}{\dtlcolumnindex{tags}{nr}}
```

Since this was a simple change, this is what I ended up using.